# Generated jss class name customization?

Tags: material-ui

I'm working on a micro frontend proof of concept app using single-spa, react, and material-ui. I've run into an issue where the generated class names from Mui are stomping on each other because there are multiple separate apps being registered with the parent app, and each child app has it's own Mui class name generator.

**Example**

Child app one is a `Drawer` for left navigation, and is adding the following `<style />` element to the `head`:

```
<style data-jss="" data-meta="MuiDrawer">
...
.jss3 {
  left: 0;
  right: auto;
}
...
</style>
```

Child app two is an `AppBar` providing top navigation, and is adding the following `<style />` element to the `head`:

```
<style data-jss="" data-meta="MuiAppBar">
...
.jss3 {
  top: 0;
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
...
</style>
```

These clobbering names result in that class (among others) to end up looking like this when I inspect the `MuiDrawer` element:

```
.jss3 {
    top: 0;
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

I've been through the Mui documentation and issues trying to figure out if there is a way to customize the naming in each app, so one might generate `.app1-jss3` and the other might generate `.app2-jss3`. So far I haven't found anything that seems to address this. Looking for some direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution:

```
import JssProvider from 'react-jss/lib/JssProvider';
import { createGenerateClassName } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName({
  seed: 'app1'
});

function App() {
  return (
    <JssProvider generateClassName={generateClassName}>
      ...
    </JssProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Do you have any solution for react-jss v10. The above solution is not working for me. Struggling for last three days. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I do not. This was for a prototype that I won't be visiting again for a few months. Have you tried `disableGlobal` mentioned below and in their updated docs? https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#creategenerateclassname-options-class-name-generator

Comment: Got solution for this. Had to use StyleProvider instead of JSSProvider. It worked like a charm

Answer (score 2):

https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/ explains all your questions (why the names look like this, how to get deterministic names in production, how to prefix).

If you encounter conflicting class names it might be good to wrap a jss provider around all apps (available in react-jss).